# PySpark: AttributeError: 'PipelineModel' object has no attribute 'clusterCenters'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means

I created a kmeans algorithm with Pypsark. Now, I want to also extract the cluster centers. How do I include it in the pipeline? This is the code that I have so far, but it throws me an error 'AttributeError: 'PipelineModel' object has no attribute 'clusterCenters'. How can it be fixed?

```
#### model K-Means ###

from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel

kmeans = KMeans() \
          .setK(3) \
          .setFeaturesCol("scaledFeatures")\
          .setPredictionCol("cluster")

# Chain indexer and tree in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[kmeans])

model = pipeline.fit(matrix_normalized)

cluster = model.transform(matrix_normalized)

#get cluster centers
centers = model.clusterCenters()
```

Comment: could be model[0].clusterCenter()?

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me TypeError: 'PipelineModel' object is not subscriptable

Comment: sorry, need to use model.stage to access the iterable inside the pipeline model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dummy data

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Pipeline


data = [(Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0]),), (Vectors.dense([1.0, 1.0]),),
        (Vectors.dense([9.0, 8.0]),), (Vectors.dense([8.0, 9.0]),)]
matrix_normalized = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["scaledFeatures"])
```

your code

```
kmeans = KMeans() \
          .setK(3) \
          .setFeaturesCol("scaledFeatures")\
          .setPredictionCol("cluster")

# Chain indexer and tree in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[kmeans])

model = pipeline.fit(matrix_normalized)

cluster = model.transform(matrix_normalized)
```

just change the last line

```
model.stages[0].clusterCenters()

[array([0.5, 0.5]), array([8., 9.]), array([9., 8.])]
```